# How does one have a for loop borrow the iterator?

Tags: rust

How does one have a `for` ... `in` loop borrow the iterator it is operating over? For example:

```
let x = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
let i = x.iter();
for a1 in i { break; } // iterate over just one "i"
for a2 in i { break; } // continue iterating through "i" here
```

You can't simply give `&i` to the for, because then it can't convert the `&Iterator` to an `Iterator` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Iterator::by_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref) to borrow the iterator and continue to use it after the borrow ends:

```
fn main() {
    let x = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mut i = x.iter();
    for _ in i.by_ref() { break; } // iterate over just one "i"
    for _ in i.by_ref() { break; } // continue iterating through "i" here
    assert_eq!(Some(&3), i.next())
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it fails if you want to have (even non-mutable) nested iterators on `i`.

Answer (score 1):

All iterators have a [`next()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next) function that advances the iterator and returns an `Option<Self::Item>` (that is, they return either `None` or a `Some` containing a value of whatever type you're iterating over. You can call this function yourself to manually increment the iterator however many times you want, which sounds like it would solve your problem in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a mutable reference to the iterator (`&mut i`):

```
let x = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
let mut i = x.iter();
for a1 in &mut i { break; }
for a2 in &mut i { break; }
```

This is the same as what `Iterator::by_ref` does internally.